# Unidentified network, no internet access just on my laptop

Tags: networking

I cannot go to internet on my laptop, but all other devices, PC, phone normally can.
Here is my ipconfig /all output:

```
    Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Delluser-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : labs.pbs.com

   Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-65-9D-3E-11-66
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

   Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : labs.pbs.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-65-9D-3E-11-66
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::259e:8466:5749:d22e%34(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 1. ožujka 2014. 17:44:42
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 2. ožujka 2014. 5:46:42
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 572286365
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-75-09-2D-F0-4D-A2-4A-EA-28
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

   Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F0-4D-A2-4A-EA-28
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

   Tunnel adapter isatap.{D0C9A875-A23E-4F87-9CD0-1CA89B3DB43C}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

   Tunnel adapter isatap.{8EAC27A2-81AC-451D-B462-3170B1C746E1}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

   Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 19:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

   Tunnel adapter isatap.labs.pbs.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

I have tried so many suggested fixes I have found on the internet, but nothing helped.
I have:

- uninstalled/installed my network card drivers
- cleaned TCP/IP stack
- applied Microsoft available Fix it solution
- changed my MAC address (via 'Technitium MAC address changer' program and manually (Network adapters > Properties > Advanced))
- changed that my computer can not turn it off in order to save power (Network adapters > Properties > Power Management)
- put firewall down for home network
- enable/disable wireless
- restarting my router
- restarting my laptop
- do not have bonjour service on my laptop so I did not have to disable it, as I have read somewhere it could cause problems
- do not use Norton or MacFee antivirus protection, I use AVG

But none of this helped.
Please, does anyone have any suggestions how to fix this, maybe I am doing something wrong?
It was working fine, suddenly it just stopped.
The only thing I have noticed is that Windows has downloaded and applied some kind of Skype update, so I do not understand why is this happening.
Any kind of advice is very much appreciated.
Thank you in advance,
mismas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a software issue, the other thing I can think of is if blocking MACID is enabled in the firmwire of your modem/router.
Because I do see that your PC is getting an IP from the modem (under the wireless adapter) but it can not browse. It can happen when the Block MAC ID feature is enabled in the modem firmwire, which allows only the devices that you will allow to connect to the internet.
Majority of the new modems have this option in the firmwire which is by default disabled.

Cheers.

Comment: My router does not have that option visible, unfortunately. So, I am guessing it is not enabled (as far as I know/can assume). But, I have called my Internet Service Provider and with the help of the operator who answered the call we created new Wireless Access Point under WiFi settings of router interface. Nothing special about it, everything was the same as for the WAP which already existed. AND mysteriously it suddenly works on every device; PC, mobile AND my laptop. It drives me crazy, I can not understand why is this happening. Do you maybe have some reasonable explanation? :D

Comment: But, thank you for your advices, it was not direct solution of my problems, but it guided me to the right path, so I will accept your answer as the solution :) Thanks again for your time and advice!

Comment: It was a case of corrupted WAN profile in your operating system. My bad, thought you already did that during troubleshooting. Glad you are connected. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please check

a.if there's a hard switch to turn on/off your Wi-Fi network(usually on the sides/front of laptops).  If it's off then turn it on.

b. sometimes the wireless needs to be enabled in BIOS.
   You may need to look it up as well.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, but the things you are talking about seem ok to me. My BIOS settings are: Wireless (Switch) / (Hotkey): All, Internal Bluetooth: Enabled, Internal WLAN: Enabled, Internal WWAN: Enabled. My laptop is DELL Studio 1558 and it does not have hard switch, instead it has a button with which I can turn on/off Wi-Fi network and I tried turning it off and then on again, but it did not help :( Do you have any other suggestions that could help?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the culprit was Photoshop CS3 or, to be more specific, one of the Adobe services that was added to the service stack during PS installation.
 Start by creating a restore point (just to on the safe side).
Then press Windows key + R (or click the Start button), type **msconfig**, select the **Services** tab and see if you can locate a string that starts with **##Id_String?.6844F930** (followed by a bunch of other stuff. *NOTE:* The question mark after **Id_String** stands for either 1 or 2. Anyway, its *Manufacturer* field should read **Apple Computer, Inc.** )
If you do have such a service, stop it by unchecking its checkbox. After rebooting you should have your life back.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problem after uninstall Network Driver **(RealTec PCIe FE Family Controller)**

1: Uninstall RealTec PCIe FE Family Controller (PC->Manage->Network Driver)

2: Wifi Off, Airplan mode Off

3: Plug your Ethernet Wire

4: Will start identifying and **Done**.

Thanks I am using Window 10

Answer (score 0):

if you'r os windows 7,8 or 10 you can try windows restore or reset pc.
if nothing is working for you